# error: reading specific rows and columns in .xlsx file in R

Tags: r, excel

I have to read a specific rows and columns in .xlsx file in R
I tried this:

```
library(xlsx)
rm(list=ls())
getwd()
setwd("/Users/EmilyJiang/Desktop/duke_sem2/coursera/Getting and cleaning data/ps1-3")
colIndex <- 18:23
rowIndex <- 7:15
ps1Subset <- read.xlsx("getdata-data-DATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, 
                   colIndex=colIndex, rowIndex=rowIndex, header = TRUE)
```

But there is an error saying:

> Error in strsplit(names(res), "\.") : non-character argument

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried reading different columns, tried any other library or tried to read the entire file? You can always discard columns once you have everything in R. I suspect it will be very hard to pin down the problem without the file in hand (no need linking to it). You need to pin down the problem by reading the data in waves. Try first few rows first. If that works, proceed until the function craps out again. Examine the offending line/column. Fix problem and rejoice.

Comment: From the error, maybe the string separator used for `strsplit` is not one but 2 chars: `\.` is 2 chars!

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed rows with columns. Change code to:

```
rowIndex <- 18:23
colIndex <- 7:15
```

It should work